# Lumen route with period

Tags: php, laravel, routes, lumen, fastroute

In Laravel I can simply have an route with period like so:

```
Route::get('/foo.bar', function() {
  return 'Hello';
});
```

But in Lumen :

```
$router->get('/foo.bar', function() {
  return 'Hello';
});
```

This always returns 404 error:

> The requested resource `/foo.bar` was not found on this server.

Please tell me why can't we have routes containing periods?

Any help would be great appreciated.

P.S:

If I replace the period with dash ( - ) or underscore ( _ ) it works fine.

Comment: Hi Hamed, what version of Lumen are you using? I have tested this just now on Lumen 5.5.1 route /foo.bar works fine.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Lumen 5.5. But I also tried on 5.3 same result :(

Comment: Please clone this repo and see for your self. https://gitlab.com/karingisi/lumentest

Comment: Same error. I find out something. If I enter the URL like this: `localhost:8000/index.php/foo.bar` it works fine! weird

Comment: I think it's a WebServer problem! is't it?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is a server configuration issue.
If using Apache try configuring .htaccess to remove .index.php when serving the page